# Using bookmark parameter with /users/

Tags: desire2learn

I have been reviewing the documentation located at http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html

I am trying to paginate the number of response i get from /users/.

When i send a get with "/users/" I recieve the expected Json block with all of the users in D2L.

When i try "/users?bookmark=3004" I recieve a 404 error or a path not found error (I have tried many variations on this line of code)

Any asistance  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the route ends with a slash: "/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/users/". This means that your call needs to look something like this:

```
https://your.lms.domain/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/?x_b={userId}&x_a={appId}&x_d={userSig}&x_c={appSig}&x_t={timestamp}&bookmark=3004
```